# How to do Encryption using open ssl(BIO) using C++?

Tags: c++, encryption, openssl

How to do Encryption using open ssl(BIO) using C++?

Comment: 30 questions and only 5% of accepted answers. You might want to fix this **first** so that people actually **want** to help you.

Comment: http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/BIO_f_ssl.html. There is an example here, did you try this at all ?

Comment: yes i tried this but this doc doesn't say about encryption

Comment: http://michalhr.ehost.pl/blog/?p=94